# Change navigation bar title color in android

Tags: android

Here I attached my screen. How can I change my navigation title color in android.

[image]

Can you observe in the title I have mentioned **MY PROFILE** in default white color but I want to change the color of it.

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <!-- Set proper title size -->
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar</item>
    <!-- Set title color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help.

```
 <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/green</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add color Programatically do this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
```

And initialize the color value in `colors.xml`:

```
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add color dynamically, please go through below code.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView("your custom layout file for actionbar");
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("Set your color in hex"));
        View view = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
```